# Is it possible to use other controller page as a firstpage at navigation base template?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am new at the area of Objective-C. I am trying to build an iPhone app by using **navigation based template**.

As usually at the navigation based template show `UITableView` page at first, but I would like to show **other** controller page at the starting of this app that `UIView` page.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The UITableViewController is created in the xib file, replace that with whatever controller you want and make sure you change it in the .h to the right type.